# How do I avoid black-spotted fairway that decreases my shot power?

Tags: mario-golf-gbc

Sometimes when I land on the fairway the terrain icon will show a black patch on the fairway. When I take my next shot, the numbers in the bottom right show my shot's power is decreased to 90-94%.

Why do some patches of fairway have black spots that decrease my shot power? Is there a way I can avoid them?

[image: Landing on black spotted fairway]
[image: Decreased power]

Comment: Do you mean the black spots under the ball? Do you have an example of when those black spots aren't present as well?

Comment: @TimmyJim Yes, I mean the black spots. You can see [non-spotted fairway in this video](https://youtu.be/N1tFslzICPU?t=1251) on holes 1 and 2, then [spotted fairway on the first shot of hole 4](https://youtu.be/N1tFslzICPU?t=1418).